# Why does each service need permissions to access something?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions

This whole idea the give permissions is so time wasting, why is it done and what does it give me in AWS for benefits?

Can´t just every service of my account access anything by default and if I wanted a weird permission system for my account, I would need to use a checkbox.

Comment: Cleaning up after your all-powerful credentials have been used to launch $20k worth of Bitcoin mining instances in EC2 or a terabyte of child porn on your S3 bucket is "so time wasting" too.

Comment: (That said, if you want to take that risk: [add the `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess` policy to your IAM user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/AdministratorAccess.html))

Comment: @ceejayoz how can this happen? I just want permissions from other services, if it is my account by default, not other accounts.

Comment: @ceejayoz ah, it is a security measure, in case my code tries to access something, which I dont want to.

Comment: Yep. For example: https://www.businessinsider.com/aws-crypto-mining-hacks-amazon-cloud-customers-huge-bills-fees-2022-1